# change select box into text box in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<select style="height:25px;"class="textbox">
    <option selected>Select item</option>
    <option value="1" >Gold cad.</option>
    <option value="2">Gold rawa</option>
    <option value="3">Silver 9999</option>
    <option value="4">Silver chorsa</option>
</select>
```

I want to show select box element in textbox by replacing select box with text box on click

Comment: So if the user accidentally clicks the wrong item they're stuck with it? What about users who make their selection via the keyboard?

Comment: i am wondering why would you like to do that. I think what you are trying to say here is a autocomplete textbox just like you get when you search in facebook or google.

Answer (score 2):

Refer this **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/CT8TT/1/)**

### Javascript:

```
var dropDown = document.getElementById("dropdown")
dropDown.onchange = function() {
    var dropDownValue = this.options[this.selectedIndex];
    dropDown.style.display = 'none';

    var textBox = document.getElementById("textbox");
    textBox.style.display = 'block';
    textBox.value = dropDownValue.text;
};
```

### HTML:

```
<select style="height:25px;" id="dropdown">     
    <option selected>Select item</option>     
    <option value="1" >Gold cad.</option>     
    <option value="2">Gold rawa</option>     
    <option value="3">Silver 9999</option>     
    <option value="4">Silver chorsa</option> 
</select>
<input type="text" id="textbox" class="inactive" />
```

### CSS:

```
.inactive {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this helps you:

```
$('select.textbox').change(function(){
  $('<input>')
     .attr('name', $(this).attr('name'))
     .val($(this)
     .find('option:selected'))
     .insertAfter($(this).hide());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For example

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>无标题文档</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function  toggle()
  {
      var div=document.getElementById("Show");
      if(div.style.display=="none")
      {
          div.style.display="block";
      }
      else

      {
          div.style.display="none";
      }
  }
  function changeText (value)
  {
      document.getElementById("text").value=value;
      toggle();
  }

</script>
</head>

<body>
<input id="text" type="text"  width="150px" height="20px" onfocus="toggle()" />
<div id="Show"   style="width:150px; display:none; border:1px solid red"    >
<div style="border-bottom:1px solid #03F" onclick="changeText('1')">Gold cad</div>
<div  style="border-bottom:1px solid #03F" onclick="changeText('2')">Gold rawa</div>
<div  style="border-bottom:1px solid #03F" onclick="changeText('3')">Silver 9999</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

this is example ,even it so bad.