# Entering a custom value on form if certain select option was clicked

Tags: javascript, forms, select, textbox

**There is a similar question to mine located here:**
[change select box into text box in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131455/change-select-box-into-text-box-in-javascript)

However, this does not completely address what I am trying to do.  So I will use their working code that comes close to what I am trying to do and then elaberate from there.

**This is the working code that they have so far:**
http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/CT8TT/1/

Javascript:

```
var dropDown = document.getElementById("dropdown")
dropDown.onchange = function() {
    var dropDownValue = this.options[this.selectedIndex];
    dropDown.style.display = 'none';

    var textBox = document.getElementById("textbox");
    textBox.style.display = 'block';
    textBox.value = dropDownValue.text;
};
```

**But here is what I want, but am having trouble figuring out how to do:**

In their version of this code, the select box turns into a text box when an option is selected.  And the text (not the value) is placed in that text box automatically.

But I want the text box to appear ONLY when a certain item is selected (as apposed to any of them) and a default value appear in the text box automatically.

**Explanation of what I am doing so you understand better:**

It's a simple donation button.  People select a predetermined amount (the first few options) -or- they select the last option which is "custom amount".  If they choose "Custom Amount", the selction box turns into a text box with a 0.00 in it.

*Seems simple enough but I am more of a PHP person as apposed to javascript but this needs to be done primarily in javascript (other than the form handling later).*

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: It's just an `if` statement, they're almost identical in PHP and Javascript.

Comment: Does the original code really work? I don't think `text` is a valid property, it should be `innerText`.

Comment: have look into this.. http://jsfiddle.net/CT8TT/96/

Comment: What if they want to go back to one of the values from the menu? If the select box disappears, how can they do that?

Comment: Why would they need to be stuck if they changed their mind?  If they decide later than they wanted one of the first options, they can just type that number in as the cutom value (or just reload the form).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var dropDown = document.getElementById("dropdown")
dropDown.onchange = function() {
    var dropDownValue = this.value;
    if (dropDownValue == "custom") { // This tests for the `<option value="custom">
        dropDown.style.display = 'none';
        var textBox = document.getElementById("textbox");
        textBox.style.display = 'block';
        textBox.value = '0.0';
    } else {
        dropDown.style.display = 'block';
        textBox.style.display = 'none';
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you.  I changed "block" to "inline" in order to prevent an additional space below the form shoing up on option changes but other than that, just perfect.

Answer (score 0):

```
dropDown.onchange = function() {
    var dropDownValue = this.options[this.selectedIndex];
    if (dropDownValue.text != "Custom Amount")
        return;
    dropDown.style.display = 'none';

    var textBox = document.getElementById("textbox");
    textBox.style.display = 'block';
    textBox.value = dropDownValue.text;
};
```

You could also - if you don't like matching a string value - check if this.selectedIndex == this.options.length (check if the selected item is the last)

Comment: Also just to irk JavaScript fans, i used != instead of !== and == instead of === :P

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/CT8TT/95/

```
var dropDown = document.getElementById("dropdown")
dropDown.onchange = function() {
  var dropDownValue = this.options[this.selectedIndex];
  if (dropDownValue.value == 4) {
    dropDown.style.display = 'none';

    var textBox = document.getElementById("textbox");
    textBox.style.display = 'block';
    textBox.value = dropDownValue.text;
  }
};
```

you can check for a specific value and only do it for this specific value.
To set the value instad of the text you need to write *dropDownValue.value* instead of
 *dropDownValue.text* for *textBox.value.*

Answer (score 0):

```
  dropDown.onchange = function() {
    var dropDownValue = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
    if (dropDownValue != "Custom Amount")
        return;
    dropDown.style.display = 'none';

    var textBox = document.getElementById("textbox");
    textBox.style.display = 'block';
    textBox.value = dropDownValue.text;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS classes to determine the values that have to become a textField.

http://jsfiddle.net/bruno2c/CT8TT/97/

Example:

```
   var dropDown = document.getElementById("dropdown")
dropDown.onchange = function () {
    var dropDownValue = this.options[this.selectedIndex];
    if (hasClass(dropDownValue, 'custom')) {
        dropDown.style.display = 'none';
        var textBox = document.getElementById("textbox");
        textBox.style.display = 'block';
        textBox.value = dropDownValue.text;
    }
};
// http://sonnyt.com/javascript-check-if-element-has-class/
function hasClass(element, className) {
    return element.className && new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + className + "(\\s|$)").test(element.className);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var dropDown = document.getElementById("dropdown")
dropDown.onchange = function() {
    var dropDownValue = this.options[selectedIndex];
    dropDown.style.display = 'none';

    var textBox = document.getElementById("textbox");
    textBox.style.display = 'block';
    textBox.value = dropDownValue.text;
};
```